# Yii2 Yii.js Not Loading

Tags: yii2

Greeting,

I have modified the configuration to specify the Assets folder is in another directory. All works fine, except it is still trying to load `Yii.js` from the original assets folder.

My configuration change is:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'basePath' => '@frontend/runtime/assets',
     ]
 ]
```

However, it is still trying to load `yii.js` from the temporary folder in `@frontend/assets` instead of `@frontend/runtime/assets`.  It DOES copy the `yii.js` file to the `@frontend/runtime/assets` folder.

Comment: Usually assets are copied to `@frontend/web/assets`. `@frontend/assets` are where the AppAsset.php-file is. What is your server setup? runtime should not be web accessible, so it would be a bad place to have it.

Comment: Duly noted, runtime was a bad example.  However, it still seems odd that yii would respect the configuration to copy yii.js to the directory specified in the basePath configuration, but would then ignore that when trying to load it.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked about the server config. Is the runtime folder actually web accessible? I'm thinking it does a fallback to the default if its not found (just speculation)

Comment: No special server config... being run on localhost without an .htaccess file, so web folder should be accessible.  Changing the basePath is not a requirement, so I may just abandon trying to do this, just thought this behavior was kind of weird.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Yep. Consider reporting it as an issue on github maybe.